# React Native App crashes on IOS simulator (assertion failed: 19H2 18B79: libxpc.dylib + 50260)

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm quite new to React Native, this is the first time I eject and I have an issue with IOS simulator.

I've ejected successfully and I can launch the app on Android simulator but every time I run yarn ios, it builds the app, bundles correctly, launches the app on simulator and crashes instantaneously.

Everything is up to date, I've reinstalled Xcode and Cocoapods but it still won't launch.

Here's the error message I get in the system log:
`assertion failed: 19H2 18B79: libxpc.dylib + 50260 [BDCDB527-0E34-3346-8444-E8CEEF0377ED]: 0x7d`

I don't really know what do with this. Is there something that could give me more information on what provokes the error ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Daft question, but can you remember if you ever found a solution to this? I'm having the same issue on iOS 13 simulators :(

Comment: @mylogon No sorry, I can't remember. I know that I managed to make the app work on IOS, but no clue as to how I solved this problem.

Comment: This turned out to be a red herring for me in the end. The underlying issue was the firebase performance sdk was just making iOS 13 quit the app immediately after booting the app straight after this ^ assert fail log.